# Modify SkyDrive synchronising direction

Tags: onedrive

How can I tell SkyDrive to not sync my files in the cloud-to-myHDD direction, but to continue syncing my files in the myHDD-to-cloud direction?

i.e., I sometimes want to add files to my SkyDrive cloud account but do not want those files downloaded to my HDD.

Answer (score 1):

When adding files you don't want synchronised to your hard drive make sure you put them in a folder you have chosen to exclude from the process. [For example](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-select-onedrive-folders-sync).